# ASP.NET MVC Enumerable to delimited HTML in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I discovered that I can use `string.Join(", ", string[] enumerable)` to turn a list of strings into a single comma delimited string. Could I do something similar to produce for example a list of hyperlinks in a Razor View? Instead of something like:

```
@foreach(var item in enumerable) 
{
    <a href="@item.Url">@item.Title</a>
    if(item != enumerable.Last()) { <span>, </span> }
}
```

And if so, would it be advisable or should I just stop being lazy?

Comment: Stop being lazy :). You would need to include the html markup in the 'comma delimited string' and use `Html.Raw()` to generate it in the view.

Comment: You're right. The accepted answer there is what I was looking for. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.Raw(string.Join("<span>, </span>", enumerable.Select(item => string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", item.Url, item.Title))))
```

Comment: Html.Raw, whilst perfectly safe in this case should always be used with caution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550149/best-practice-for-prevent-xss-hacking

Comment: Does what I asked for but, as has been pointed out, my question turns out to be a duplicate. Sorry!

Comment: Lovely one-liner for making lists with tooltips.